# Issue with WP Rest API

Tags: wordpress, api, error, rest

I've a CiviCRM 5.37 installed with a WP 5.72 in a Linux server.
As a permalink WP setting I defined the "article name" syntax.

Well, my problem is the follow:
When I create a new mail and I try to look a public view or the web browser version, I see a 404 http error.
The URL that I can view is similar to: /civicrm/mailing/view/?id=13&reset=1

If I change the URL adding "index.php" all work fine: /**index.php**/civicrm/mailing/view/?id=13&reset=1

The same problem when I call a CiviCRM API.
I need to use an URL like this: /**index.php/**wp-json/civicrm/v3/rest

This is a big problem 'cause all CiviCRM token that generate an URL doesn't work.

Why I need to add "index.php"?
How can I work correctly without adding "index.php" in all CiviCRM url?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you post your `.htaccess` file? Anonymised, of course.

Comment: Hi Christian,
I solved my issue changing the Wp permalink whit "custom structure" mode like this: <domain>/index.php/%postname%/